# Inject all values from .properties file into Properties (or Map) using @PropertySource

Tags: spring, properties-file

I'm using `Spring Framework` version `5.3.10` in an application that uses Spring JDBC for interfacing with the database.

I'm trying to isolate the SQL queries into `.properties` files. I know there are many ways for doing this, but I was wondering if there is a way to inject all the values, for a given `.properties` file referenced by `@PropertySource("classpath:database/queries.properties")` into a `Properties` (or `Map`) type.

For instance, if I were to have a "repository" (or DAO, you name it) class like this:

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:database/queries.properties")
public class ThisJdbc implements IThisJdbc {
  private final Map<String, String> sqlStore; // ...values from queries.properties here

  private final Properties sqlStore; // ...or here

  @Override
  public int[] batchInsert(final List<This> these) {
    sqlStore.get("batch-insert");
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

I would like a simple way to inject what's in the `.properties` file provided to that class via the aforementioned types — or any other available key/value type for that matter. The `.properties` files are like usual:

```
find-all = select * from tb_this

find-by-col_1 = select * from tb_this where col_1 = :col_1

insert-record = insert into tb_this values (:col_1, :col_2, :col_3)
```

> Notice that injecting `Environment` in all those classes is not an option for me ;)

I was looking for a way to use `@Value` with a fixed prefix — similar to Spring Boot's `@ConfigurationProperties`, but I couldn't find anything around that.

Basically, I'm trying to see if there is a way to use `@PropertySource` and any `Map`-like type to avoid having this:

```java
@Bean(name = "this-queries")
public PropertiesFactoryBean thisQueries() {
  final var bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
  bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("database/queries.properties"));
  return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@PropertySource` is to be used in conjunction with `@Configuration` classes. Having said that, try the following:

```java
@Repository
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:database/queries.properties")
public class ThisJdbc implements IThisJdbc {
  @Value("#{${queries}}")
  private final Map<String, String> sqlStore; // ...values from queries.properties here

  @Override
  public int[] batchInsert(final List<This> these) {
    sqlStore.get("batch-insert");
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Assuming your `queries.properties` is:

```
queries = {key1:'query1',key2:'query2',....}
```

Comment: I'm not currently using `Spring Boot`, but just `Spring Framework`; `@ConfigurationProperties` is not available for me.

Comment: In that case, I've edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: The `SpEl` expression throws something like this: `SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'`. Did you try this and worked for you? I actually don't fully understand what value(s) `${queries.properties}` is bringing into the `SpEl` expression.

Comment: My bad, I misread your code. I've updated my answer.